Can I suggest a more LEGO-y skin?
I thinks skins are a really important feature of stackexchange. Every site has it's own identity, given by the styling it uses.
The current skin we use here is lovely, I really like the sketchyness, but the problem is, it doesn't shout "LEGO" at me.
I think we ought to try and implement the brick into it a bit more. (And yes, we can do this under copyright resrictions, just look at some other LUG websites.)
Perhaps the "questions tags users badges" buttons could be bricks? Or the side of a quote could be a rotated brick.
I'm not calling for a totaly LEGO-ified style, just something that will say "LEGO" at me a bit more.

I would have used round 1x1 studs for badges.

Badges get tailored too :)

While this site is still in Beta, we're using the "sketchy" skin and we're actually very lucky to have our custom icon. Most of the other beta Stack Exchange sites only have their initials as their icon (SmugMug and Poker being a couple of exceptions). 
Once we've "graduated" out of beta, Jin the Stack Exchange designer will get involved and come up with some designs for us that we can then have a bit of a say on, but it's certainly good for us to talk about it now.

Edit to add:
Apparently we're about to lose the the sketchy skin for a more polished, plain skin:

The New Stack Exchange Beta Theme


Ah, I see, all Beta sites have the sketchy skin. That makes sense. Thanks.

@ambo100 yeah, what is that SmugMug thing, it's not even a sketchy icon ;)
